# SQL Server Database Experimentation Assistant Analysis Reports

Tags: sql-server, performance-testing

I am using the Database Experimentation Assistant v2.6 to capture a workload using extended events (`.xel`) on SQL Server 2017 that is installed on an Azure VM.  I'm then replaying it on a Azure SQL Database Managed Instance.  The capture and the replay work great. I'm getting multiple `.xel` files from the replay, 15 from the VM and 7 from the Managed Instance.

My issue is when I create the analysis report it only allows me to select 1 `.xel` file in each of the the "Trace for Target 1 SQL Server" and "Trace for Target 2 SQL Server" fields to compare.  My expectation is that I can run one report for the entire replay by selecting the directories the files are in but this does not appear to be an option?  When I try to select just the directory it will not allow me to exit the directory window.  Below is the screen I'm referring to : [image: New analysis report screenshot]

I've looked through multiple articles but the only ones I've found, including [this one from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-create-report?view=sql-server-ver15), refer to selecting only one file and normally a `.trc` file not a `.xel` file.

How can I compare multiple `.xel` files at once?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Microsoft support in regards to my question.  They informed me that even though you only select 1 `.xel` file all `.xel` files in the directory are processed and you can verify it in the log.

> ```
> DEA Information: 0 : DiagnosticEvent, 05/08/2020 16:32:47, Data: {"Message":"Processing file 1 of 7
> DEA Information: 0 : DiagnosticEvent, 05/08/2020 16:33:20, Data: {"Message":"Processing file 2 of 7
> .
> .
> .
> DEA Information: 0 : DiagnosticEvent, 05/08/2020 16:36:03, Data: {"Message":"Processing file 7 of 7
> ```

They are planning on making this more transparent in a future release.